# Updating mongo collection based on condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want my system to update a mongodb collection only when a user is authorized to do so. The information i require to check this, lies within the document itself. Therefore, i need a condition to evaluate before actually updating the collection.

The [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) say:

> "The selection criteria for the update. Use the same query selectors as used in the find() method."

which pointed me to the query operator [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)

My understanding is, that i'm able to use data from the document itself to decide if the document gets updated.

My current approach looks like this:

```
db.myCollection.update( {
    criteriaA: 'A',
    $where: function() {
        // I expect this collection to update only when
        //  `current_user_is()` returns true
        return current_user_is( this.role );
    }, {
        $set: {
            criteriaB: 'B'
        }
    }
});
```

but apparently, this inserts the document regardless of whether the function returns true or not.

To clarify:

```
db.myCollection.update( {
    criteriaA: 'A',
    $where: function() {
        // I expect this to bail the update, but it won't
        return false;
    }, {
        $set: {
            criteriaB: 'B'
        }
    }
});
```

How do i achieve this kind of conditional updating, without changing the structure of the document itself? I'm also trying to avoid querying the document beforehand (unless it's the right approach for this situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't the right approach and there are several reasons why, but let us start with your assumed usage of the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.

What [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is designed to do is execute a JavaScript condition on the database server. The documentation warns you explicitly over it's use and therefore it is generally speaking not a good idea to use.

The only real valid reasons, and even these should be avoided in favor of using the [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method instead, is where yo need to compare the value of one field in the document against another.

What you are trying to do is have this execute some code that very likely does not actually exist on the database server. Certainly for your intention, the simple thing to do is just retrieve the current users "role" and then evaluate that normally (and using native code operators rather than JavaScript) against the document you want to update. Or in basic form:

```js
var currentRoles = getUserRolesSomeHow();

db.collection.update(
    {
        "criteriaA": "A",
        "role": { "$in": currentRoles }
    },
    {
        "$set": { "criteriaB": "B" }
    }
)
```

This makes sense as such functions are "client side" ( as in client to database ) operations and are not actually performed on the server. Get your information there and pass it into your query. Your document clearly contains the "role" information for which "roles" are authorized to update it, so just use it normally.